# Подскажите , верно ли работает код?

Tags: python

Текстовый файл содержит только заглавные буквы латинского алфавита (ABC…Z). Определите максимальное количество идущих подряд символов, среди которых не более одной буквы D.

Мой код вроде бы работает верно, но я не понимаю почему, ведь я не обнуляю значение 'co' , которое отвечает за количество D в последовательности, когда всё таки встречаю вторую. Если же я его буду обнулять, то код будет выдавать ответ, больший чем нужно.

```
a = open('24.txt')
f=a.readline()
count=0
co=0
m=0
s=0
for i in range(0,1100000):
    if f[i]!='D':
        count+=1
        m=max(m,count)
    if f[i]=='D':
        if co>1:
            count=i-s
            s=i
        else:
            co+=1
            count+=1
            s=i
print(m)
```

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: Верный ответ - 354, при обнулении 'co' ответ становится равным 393

Comment: А буквы алфавита мы сами набивать будем...

Comment: В файле последовательность из 11000000 символов :) Если здесь можно прикрепить файл, то я прикреплю, но насколько я знаю, нельзя.

Comment: Составьте несколько коротких примеров, для которых ответ очевиден. Например `AAADAADAAD`  `AADAADAAAD`, `DAADAAD` и протестируйте на них.

Comment: Честно говоря, я немного сломал голову глядя на этот некомментированный код. Но вы в PyCharm по шагам пройдите и сами посмотрите, как должны переменные меняться, а как меняются.